# Effective permissions for a group

Tags: sql, permissions

We have a group "All Staff" and gave them read access to a database. But when I click Effective permissions I get the below error:

> Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal "All Staff" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.

This user has a login and is mapped to this database, which was restored to another machine. I also tried to establish a owner for the database:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION 
ON DATABASE::[database]
TO [user].
```

But it did not help.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hope this helps you https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186179/cannot-execute-as-the-database-principal-because-the-principal-does-not-exist

Comment: We are using SQL Server 2016

Comment: Thanks for the link. I checked, but that user is not orphaned. And the SID is the same.

Comment: I also tried to drop the user completely and from the databases and added it as a new user linking it to the database. It still gives me this error.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.